# Save image file to app documents directory in Swift. Does the url to App document directory change even when deployed on the device?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, save

Below are the two functions which I use in the picker view controller to save the file in the App documents directory. And save the url in the local DB & display the image using  **UIImage(contentsOfFile: ImagePathString)**

Everything works well as until this point however as soon as i re-run the simulator images does not show up. I believe its because the app directory keeps changing every time its run on the simulator. My question if its the same when deployed on the device?

```
 func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

    //Below function is used in imagePickerController

    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(modifiedImage!) {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(NSDate()).png")
        data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)
        pathImage = filename
        print(pathImage)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use writeToFile to save image in document directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836862/how-to-use-writetofile-to-save-image-in-document-directory)

Comment: my question is if the url to app documents folder change when the app is deployed on the device?

Comment: No it doesn't change

Comment: @HossamGhareeb Thank you. 
So its just in the simulator i would be facing issues displaying images when the app is rerun.

Answer (score 4):

Yes url to App documents folder may change when the app is deployed on the device. 
Refer below link
[Technical Note TN2406](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html)
.

Comment: Does it change every time the app is closed and reopned on the physical device after its deployed on it.

Comment: Not checked that. But it changes don't know when so use relative path.

Comment: Yes, you should store just the path after document directory, in your example, just the file name, and retrieving  it from document directory

Comment: IF it answers to your question then accept as answer