# Download Images from url and store into Photo Gallery in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Downloading images from the URL and showing into the table view, when I select the image it will store into the Photo Gallery. I have successfully got images from urls and showing to table view but am not able to store them into Photo Gallery after the selection of the image.

This is my code:

```
var parsingdata = [Datavalues]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    let cellvalues = parsingdata[row] as Datavalues
    cell.CategoryImage.downloadImageFrom(link: cellvalues.categoryImage, contentMode: .scaleToFill)
    cell.categoryName.text = cellvalues.categoryName
    cell.IDLabel.text = String(cellvalues.id)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let imagestring = String(parsingdata[indexPath.row].categoryImage)

//Image add name is stored into the imagestring 

    let documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Savedframe.png")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        do {
            try UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagestring)!.write(to: fileURL)
            print("Image Added Successfully")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } else {
        print("Image Not Added")
    }
}
```

Where did I do wrong? My aim is download image from url, store them into Photo Gallery when image is selected.

Comment: Local drive means in the `Photos` app?

Comment: you want to save image locally did you tried checking this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32837120/6080920

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use writeToFile to save image in document directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836862/how-to-use-writetofile-to-save-image-in-document-directory)

Comment: @Pankil yes its like our gallery

Comment: UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiimge, nil, nil, nil)

Comment: @Ngp Just do 1 thing, write below line when you select your `image`. `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil)` and replace `img` with your selected `image`.

Comment: @DixitAkabari  Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UIImage' its showing error because am passing string values to img

Comment: @Pankil let imagestring =  String(parsingdata[indexPath.row].categoryImage) my selected image name converting into string

Comment: @Ngp pass UIImage not String.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, in `didSelectRowAt` method, Convert your `image` string to `URL` and convert it into `Data`, Once Image is created as `Data` than save it like below.

If your images are of large size than you need to convert `URL` to `Data` in `background thread` and save `image` to `photosAlbum` in `main thread`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let imagestring = String(parsingdata[indexPath.row].categoryImage)

    if let url = URL(string: imagestring),
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
        let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works but just a reminder you need to add `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` this key to your `Info.plist` and provide a description for this method to work.