# What am I doing wrong on using USerDefault to save data

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm encoding images selected by the user, then saving to USerDefault. So, I retrieve these images by decoding and converting to an Array of UIImages, where I populate my UITableView. My goal is being able to terminate the App and when I open again, the UITableView still populated, I want to persist the user data.
Everything worked perfectly, I got what I wanted but after a couple tries I got the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   ' -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty
>   NSArray'

What would be the best way for me to do what I want?

***Here is where the data should be retrieved:***

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource, dataReceivedDelegate {

    func dataReceived(nameSaved: NSArray) {
        nameSaved1 = nameSaved
//        imagemCell = fotoSaved
       self.itensTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var itensTableView: UITableView!

    //Notification
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    //
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "DD07D751-FBE1-430C-973A-281F9DA59A39")!, identifier: "Estimotes")

    var arrayNomes = NSMutableArray()
    var nomeReceived = ""
    var qtd:Int = 0
    var imagemCell = [NSData]()
    var nameSaved1 = NSArray()
    var dataSaved = [NSData]()
    var imageSaved = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "namesSavedArray") == true{
            nameSaved1 = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "namesSavedArray") as! [String] as NSArray
            itensTableView.reloadData()
        }
        if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "fotoSaved") == true{
            // Load the image
            imagemCell = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "fotoSaved") as! [NSData]
            for uiimage in imagemCell {
                let imageConverted = UIImage(data: uiimage as Data)
                imageSaved.append(imageConverted!)

                itensTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        //LocationManager
        locationManager.delegate = self
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)

    }


    func isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: String) -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "addVc" {
            let vc:adicionarNovoItemVc = segue.destination as! adicionarNovoItemVc
            vc.delegate = self

        }
    }


    func rangeBeacons(){
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "DD07D751-FBE1-430C-973A-281F9DA59A39")
        let major:Int = 1
        let minor:Int = 1
        let identifier = "Bruz IBeacon"

        let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid!, major: CLBeaconMajorValue(major), minor: CLBeaconMinorValue(minor), identifier: identifier)

        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        switch status {
        case .restricted:
            print("Location access was restricted.")
        case .denied:
            print("User denied access to location.")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Location status not determined.")
        case .authorizedAlways: fallthrough
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Location status is OK.")

        }

        if status == .authorizedAlways{

            rangeBeacons()
        }
    }
    // Handle incoming location events.
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
        print("Location: \(location)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        guard let discoveredBeacon = beacons.first?.proximity else {
            print("Beacon nao encontrado"); return}

            switch discoveredBeacon {

            case .immediate:
                beaconMuitoProximo()
                self.view.backgroundColor = .green
            case .near: break
//                beaconProximo()
//                self.view.backgroundColor = .orange
            case .far:
                beaconLonge()
                self.view.backgroundColor = .red
            case .unknown:
                self.view.backgroundColor = .black
        }


    }
    // Handle location manager errors.
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    func beaconMuitoProximo(){

        //Notificacoes de perda de objetos
//        self.content.title = "Seguro"
//        self.content.body = "Suas coisas estao perto de voce =)"
//        self.content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
//        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
//        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testIdentifierPerto", content: self.content, trigger: trigger)
//        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
//



    }
    func beaconProximo(){


    }
    func beaconLonge(){


        // create a sound ID, in this case its the tweet sound.
        let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016

        // to play sound
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)

    }


    @IBAction func botaoAdicionar(_ sender: UIButton) {}


    //TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //        let item = objetos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! tableviewCell
        cell.nameCell.text =  nameSaved1[indexPath.row] as? String//Nil value
        cell.imageViewCell.image = imageSaved[indexPath.row] //Nil value
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return imageSaved.count
    }
}
```

***Here is where I'm saving the data:***

```
protocol dataReceivedDelegate {
    func dataReceived(nameSaved:NSArray)
}

class adicionarNovoItemVc: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldNome: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var namePreview: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imagePreview: UIImageView!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    var arrayName = [String]()
    var arrayFotoData = [NSData]()
    var delegate:dataReceivedDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textFieldNome.delegate = self

        if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "namesSavedArray") == true{
            arrayName = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "namesSavedArray") as! [String]
        }
        if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: "fotoSaved") == true{
            arrayFotoData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "fotoSaved") as! [NSData]
        }
    }

    func isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: String) -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
    }

    @IBAction func botaoAdcFoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        if let mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary) {
            picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
        }
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.imagePreview.image = image
            self.namePreview.text = self.textFieldNome.text

            //Encode Image
            let dataSaved:NSData = image.pngData()! as NSData
            arrayFotoData.append(dataSaved)

            UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayFotoData, forKey: "fotoSaved")
        }
        self.picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.textFieldNome.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func botaoAdcItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (self.namePreview!.text != nil) && (self.imagePreview!.image != nil) {
            if delegate != nil {

                arrayName.append(self.namePreview.text!)

                delegate?.dataReceived(nameSaved: arrayName as NSArray)

                UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayName, forKey: "namesSavedArray")

                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
        else {return}
}


}
```

***That's how the app should work:
 This screen is where the UITableView is located, so the data should be persist here:***

[image: Here]

***This screen is where the data should be set and saved:
After press the button, the screen should be dismissed and reload the UITableView containing the data.***

[image]

Comment: `UserDefaults` is a bad choice for saving images and data.

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion on how I should do that dude?

Comment: Write the images as files.

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Comment: @TituJow you should convert image to Data and save it to App's Document folder by `write` function https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779858-write

Comment: @QuocNguyen Hello! Man, can you provide me an example, please?

Comment: @TituJow https://stackoverflow.com/a/32837120/2776008 you can see here

Comment: How do I retrieve the data after saved? @QuocNguyen

Comment: @TituJow you can save the image link. When you need to get the image, just read from saved link

Comment: Multiple arrays as table data source are error-prone and could cause such problems because the number of items must be in sync. Use a custom struct or class instead. And this is Swift 3+: No `NSArray`, no `NSData`. And rather than the extra `isKeyPresentInUserDefaults` method use optional binding with `if let` or register the keys as Apple recommends.

Comment: Please only show _relevant_ code in your question. For example, what does `func beaconLonge()` have to do with updating `UserDefaults`? Please create a [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the Objective-c version of the code which you may need, kindly try to create the swift version.

So, to **save/write the image data** to the application's folder you can do as

```
 //to write the image in folder
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

[pngData writeToFile:[[AlertHelper sharedAlertManager] documentsPathForFileName:@"The name for your image"] atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

I have used an helper method in the above code to ease the process and use it in at various class files.

And to **Read the image data**,

```
  NSData *pngData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[AlertHelper sharedAlertManager] documentsPathForFileName:@"The same name you used to write for your image"]];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData1];
```

> And the Helper methood is

```
// to write and read files in paths
- (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name]); // to check if the name used for image.
    return [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
}
```

**UPDATE:-**

For the Swift Version i came across [something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354779/6786974) which may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having related to the as! [String]

Just because the key exists doesn’t mean that you won’t get nil back.

Use as? [String] ?? []

So if nil is returned you will have an empty array.

Answer (score -3):

Just call **UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()** after set new value to UserDefault, it should trigger a synchronization for actually storing new value.

Comment: From Apple's documentation…  `synchronize()` _"… this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize